# Django creating sub fields

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django. I am trying to find out is it possible to create a field in django that takes multiple interlinked inputs.

**For example:**

I am trying to create a student evaluation record in which I would like to store marks of each student subject wise. For this I want a field like:

**subject1**  `(drop down menu to select subject) (Max. marks) (marks obtained)`,

**subject2**  `(drop down menu to select subject) (Max. marks) (marks obtained)`
and so on..

Can I do this?
OR is there a better way to do this like when I enter the degree or course persued by a student in the previous field , it fetches me the list of subjects under that particular degree and same way I can enter marks for each subject. So that it would be easier to display student wise record as well as subject wise.

Plz help.. thanks in advance !!

Reply to first ans:
not working yet.. either I cudn't get you or I am implementing it wrong
here's the code. where am I going wrong?

```py
    
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name='Evaluation_Students')
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject', related_name='Evaluation_Subjects')

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.Evaluation_Students
   

class Student(models.Model):
   Student_First_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default = 0)
   Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 0)
   Registeration_Number = models.CharField(max_length = 12,default=0,unique=True)
   SelectDegree = models.CharField(max_length=100,default = 0,choices=Allowed_courses)
   Subjects= models.CharField(max_length = 100,choices=Subjects,default='-')
   evaluations = models.ManyToManyField('Evaluation')

   def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.Student_First_Name, self.Last_Name)
    

class Subject(models.Model):
   SelectSubject = models.CharField(max_length = 4,choices=Subjects)
   Test_Type = models.CharField(max_length = 12,default= '-')
   Maximum_marks = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
   Marks_Obtained =  models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create an additional model called Evaluation and link it to student with a ManyToMany Field.

```
Student model:
     fields…
     evaluations = models.ManyToManyField(Evaluation)


Evaluation model:
      student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
      subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
      mark = models.CharField(…whatever…)
```

You can also do this without the Many to Many field and manage the relationship yourself.  For example, add a property in the student model:

```
 Student model:

       @property
       def evaluations(self):
            return Evalution.objects.filter(student=self)
```

Comment: not working yet.. either I cudn't get you or I am implementing it wrong
here's the code. where am I going wrong?